# text/xml return from rest call

Tags: wcf, rest

When I make a standard Get Request call to a restful wcf service it returns with a content type of "application/xml". A vendor is asking we send with a content type of "text/xml". How do I switch this in wcf? Is it an attribute?

The call is this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, Namespace = "")]
[XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, Use=OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
public class Player
{

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}")]
    public string GetTestDetailsRequest(string id)
    {
        TestService.TestServiceClient testServiceClient = new TestServiceClient();
        string xml = testServiceClient.GetTestDetailsRequest(Guid.Parse(id));
        return xml;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the content type:

`WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";`

Answer (score 1):

Don't try and use WCF to call RESTful services.  Just use HttpWebRequest or HttpClient, that way you will have control over your request.

Comment: HttpClient is included in WCF Rest Starter Kit Preview 2. http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644

Comment: @Joey That HTTPClient is no longer supported.  There is a new one at http://wcf.codeplex.com

Comment: thanks. Seems like the REST stack in WCF keeps changing ... forgot Glen took over it.